# Como serializar objetos C# a un archivo JSON o XML

Tags: c#, json, serialización

Estoy trabajando con un sistema de un hospital y me gustaría saber como podría exportar la información de mis objetos a archivos con un formato legible como `JSON` o `XML`, para usarlos como entrada de otro programa que los procese.

Estas son mis clases:

```
public class Patient
{
    public string PatienName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public char Sex { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public Illness Illness { get; set; }

    public Bed Bed { get; set; }
}

public class Bed
{
    public int BedNumber { get; set; }
    public string Aisle { get; set; }
}

public class Illness
{
    public IllnessType Type { get; set; }
    public string IllnessName { get; set; }
}

public class IllnessType
{
    public string IllnessTypeName { get; set; }
    public string Severity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Necesitas agregar mas detalles, como por ejemplo si usas un framework y que has intentado, difícilmente alguien va resolver tu problema.

Comment: Hola @Gemasoft creo que para este caso en especial, no es tan complicado,  ya que es algo "comun" y de hecho ya tuvo 3 respuestas ;)

Comment: @jasilva Si te fijas la pregunta es muy amplia y esta basada en opiniones, cada respuesta es muy distinta por lo tanto creo que necesita agregar mas detalles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te pongo una respuesta de como convertir código de clases con XML.

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Patient NewPatient = new Patient()
            {
                Age = 35,
                Address = "Apple red #159",
                Bed = new Bed()
                {
                    Aisle = "54A",
                     BedNumber = 145,

                },
                Illness = new Illness()
                {
                    IllnessName = "Stomach ache",
                     Type = new IllnessType() 
                     { 
                       IllnessTypeName= "Stomach ache type",
                        Severity = "Chronic",
                     },

                },
                 PatienName = "Marisela Smith",
                  Sex = 'F',

            };

            StreamWriter MyFile = new StreamWriter(@"D:\XML.txt");

            XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Patient));
            Serializer.Serialize(MyFile,NewPatient);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Estoy pensando en serializar con JSON, pero tu solución funciona.

Answer (score 9):

Si utilizas JSON.NET (que probablemente deberías, porque es muy útil y fácil de usar cuando se utiliza JSON), podrías crear listas genéricas de sus clases y luego serializarlas a archivos JSON; por ejemplo:

```
List<Patient> patientList = new List<Patient>();
Patient p = new Patient();
p.PatienName = "Helen Keller";
p.Age = 136;
p.Sex = 'F';
. . .
patientList.Add(p);
. . .
// Entonces, después añadir los pacientes a la lista, los guardas así:    
var jsonPatientList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patientList);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Cualquiera\patients.json", patientList);
```

De manera similar lo puedes hacer con el resto de clases.

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres Xml intenta usar `System.Xml.Serialization`

```
public static void Guardar(Patient paciente,  String ruta) {
    try
    {

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Patient));

        FileStream fStream = File.Open(ruta , FileMode.Create);

        serializer.Serialize(fStream, paciente);

        fStream.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }

}
```

O uno generico para todas tus clases usado [T (Metodos genericos)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-MX/library/twcad0zb.aspx)

```
public static void Guadar<T>(T data,  String url) {
    try
    {


        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        FileStream fStream = File.Open(url , FileMode.Create);

        serializer.Serialize(fStream, data);

        fStream.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agregando a [la respuesta de @B.ClayShannon](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/4021/227), acá una forma de convertir objetos a XML utilizando .Net, no frameworks adicionales, pero sí necesitas agregar la dependencia a `System.XML`:

```
public static string Serialize(object item, bool removeNamespace = true)
{
    if (item == null)
        return null;
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    var itemType = item.GetType();
    //remueve "lo.que.sea.el.namespace.de.tu" del nombre completo de la clase: lo.que.sea.el.namespace.de.tu.ClaseConDatos
    if (removeNamespace)
    {
        var xns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        xns.Add(String.Empty, String.Empty);
        new XmlSerializer(itemType).Serialize(new StringWriter(stringBuilder), item, xns);
    }
    else
    {
        new XmlSerializer(itemType).Serialize(new StringWriter(stringBuilder), item);
    }
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Una vez obtenido como cadena, lo puedes guardar a un archivo vía

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(ruta, cadenaXml);
```

Y por si necesitas deserializarlo:

```
public static T getObjectOfXml<T>(string xmlInput, Type[] extraTypes)
{
    //Parser xml request to object
    StringReader stream = null;
    XmlTextReader reader = null;
    T returnedXmlClass = default(T);

    try
    {
        // serialise to object
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), extraTypes);
        stream = new StringReader(xmlInput); // read xml data
        reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);  // create reader
        // covert reader to object
        returnedXmlClass = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    catch
    {
        returnedXmlClass = default(T);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null) stream.Close();
        if (reader != null) reader.Close();
    }

    //Return object
    return returnedXmlClass;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres convertir tu `objeto` a `xml` con la siguiente función es muy facil y comprensible:

```
public static string GetXMLFromObject(object o) {
   try {
     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
     StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
     XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
     serializer.Serialize(tw, o);
     return sw.ToString();
   } catch (Exception ex) {
     //Handle Exception Code
   } finally {
     sw.close();
     tw.close();
   }
 }
```

Al método solo mandalé tu `objeto` y te regresará un string en formato `xml`. Solo recuerda agregar los siguiente `using` a la clase donde vayas a agregar el método.

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

Espero que te sea util.

Te coloco el [link](http://www.techillumination.in/2013/07/convert-object-to-xml-and-vice-versa.html) de donde lo saque, ahí mismo encontraras como parsear `xml` a `objeto`.