# Diferencia entre dos formatos en xml

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, xml

Quiero saber la diferencia entre estos dos formatos en XML

```
<Producto Cod=5"/>
```

Y

```
<Producto> <Cod>"5"</Cod> </Producto>
```

y como podria generar un xml a partir de un objeto con el primer formato en C#

Gracias.

Comment: alguien ya hizo la misma pregunta revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4018/como-serializar-objetos-c-a-un-archivo-json-o-xml

Comment: @MiguelZarate no me parece que sea exactamente la misma pregunta. De hecho, en la pregunta que citas, preguntan lo contrario: de c# a XML/Json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La diferencia está en que en la primera línea:

```
<Producto Cod=5"/>
```

Estás definiendo un atributo "Cod" para un elemento "Producto".

y en la segunda:

```
<Producto> <Cod>"5"</Cod> </Producto>
```

Estás definiendo un elemento "Cod" dentro del elemento "Producto".

Para leerlo y asignarlo a un objeto en C# tienes diferentes alternativas, te propongo una (no es la única ni la mejor). Obviamente no tiene validaciones de tipo/cast.:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<Producto Cod='5' />");
        var producto = new Producto{
            Cod = (int)doc.Root.Attribute("Cod")
        };                      
    }
}

public class Producto{
    public int Cod{get;set;}    
}
```

Por si quieres jugar un poco con el ejemplo, te dejo el fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KyZ1an

**UPDATE:**

Teniendo en cuenta el último comentario, en este caso ya es un poco más teórica la pregunta. Se trata de dos "enfoques" diferentes para el tratamiento de XML:

a) Centrado en atributos (primer código)
b) Centrado en elementos (segundo código)

Para el primer caso:

```
<Producto Cod="5"/>
```

"Cod" es un atributo del elemento "Producto".

Para el segundo caso:

```
<Producto>5</Producto>
```

"5" es el valor para el elemento "Producto".

Incluso se podría tener una combinación de los 2:

```
<Producto Cod="5">5</Producto>
```

Que se leería más o menos: Producto "tiene" un atributo "Cod = 5" y el valor de Producto es 5.

Todo depende del "significado" que le quieras dar al XML.

Quizás este articulo explique mejor la diferencia: https://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/09/08/attribute-centric-and-element-centric-xml/

Comment: Perdon, en realidad me exprese mal. Lo que quise poner en el segundo caso es <Producto>"5"</Producto>

Comment: Gracias. Y mediante el metodo Serialize de XmlSerializer como podria conseguir un xml con el enfoque del PRIMER caso? No se si esto tiene que ver pero el xml que me pide el web service debe tener en el encabezado lo siguiente: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

Comment: Te adjunto un pequeño extracto de que es lo que se me pide:

<Partes>
      <Parte CodLista="1">
           <NroContratoInterno>BA-300-2019</NroContratoInterno>
           <CUIT>33333333333</CUIT>
           <Sucursal CodLista="5"></Sucursal>
       </Parte>
</Partes>

Comment: Creería que sería más o menos así: https://dotnetfiddle.net/K954DL Supongo que tendrás que hacer ajustes a los espacios de nombres y eso...

Comment: Gracias por todo, fuiste de mucha ayuda.